# Design pattern to switch a state for a set of functions

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have a series of instance functions in a class. There is also a boolean instance variable that designates an object state. Almost all the instance functions depend on this boolean state. Their body looks like

```
int f() {

   if (state) {
      //do stuff
   }
   else {
      // do other stuff
   }
}
```

In addition to that some function are swapped by the state. So if state is true then when user calls f() it actually is run. But when state is false then when user calls f() what happens is that antiF() is run.

So some functions have switches inside them and some functions get swapped completely.

If I was doing this with C++ I would probably use function pointers. How would I do this with Java? A Strategy pattern?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like you want the [state pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern#Java). Instead of having each function check for the state, you pull these functions into a state interface and have separate implementations for each state:

```
public interface State {
  void f();
  void g();
  void h();
}

public class StateA : State {
  public void f() { do something; }
  ...
}

public class StateB : State {
  public void f() { do something else; }
  ...
}
```

Then instead of a boolean variable, you would maintain a specific `State` instance:

```
State currentState = new StateA();
...
currentState = new StateB();
```

Comment: Lets say StateB.g() is the same as StateA.f(). Is there a simpler solution than just to write `StateA.f(argument);` in the body of StateB.g()?

Comment: @problemofficer: In that case, I would pull all the individual pieces of functionality into a separate class and just call the various functions from the `State` objects. For example, both `StateB.g()` and `StateA.f()` could call `Foo.bar()`.